# Testing an image processing algorithm on noisy data

Tags: image-processing, noise, training-data

I wrote an  image processing program that train some classifier to recognize some object in the image. now I want to test the response of my algorithm to noise. I wish the algorithm have some robustness to noise.

My question is that, should I train the classifier using noisy version of train dataset, or train the classifier using original version of dataset, and see its performance on noisy data.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would your classifier work well in noisy conditions if you train it in clean images? Suppose you want planes recognized in B&W photographs ... Would you train the algorithm on color pictures?

Comment: my image is medical ultrasound, that has inherent speckle noise. I want to increase the noise. I seems that in noisy images the structure of objects are distorted and classifier can not learn.

Comment: The classification is pixel-wise and it must learn for example bright pixels.

Answer (score 0):

to show robustness of classifier one might use highly noisy test data on the originally trained classifier. depending on that performance, one can train again using noisy data and then test again. obviously for an application development, if including extremely noisy samples increase accuracy then that's the way to go. literature says to have as large a range of training samples as possible. however sometimes this degrades performances in specific cases.